# Micrometer vs metricbeats

Tags: elasticsearch, metrics, spring-micrometer

Looking to send metrics to elastic search. I have a number of docker services running in Springboot.
What is the difference between using micrometer and metric beats?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [nice example in the official observability documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/master/monitor-java-app.html#_step_5_ingest_metrics) on how both Metricbeat and Micrometer can be complimentary.

Micrometer provides metrics in a vendor-neutral way. Those metrics are then [pulled by Prometheus](http://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus) and Metricbeat (with the [`prometheus` module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-prometheus.html)) is used to forward those metrics to Elasticsearch.

It is also possible to remove Prometheus from the picture and simply configure Micrometer to [push metrics directly to Elasticsearch](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/elastic).

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. What do you mean by vendor-neutral way? I guess what I am trying to figure out is do I have to use micrometer? or will metric beat gives me what I need?

Comment: Then you need to first explain what (metrics) you need :-)

Comment: CPU usage, CPU load averages, Memory usage, Network IO,.....etc